# Parallel creation of complex dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, pool

The below code seems to have some issues. The aim would be to append each result of new_df() to some list, e.g. `out`.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def new_df(rows=10000):  # proxy for complex dataframe
    temp = pd.DataFrame({'a': [''.join(chr(random.randint(65,122)) for _ in range(200))
                               for _ in range(rows)]})
    temp['b'] = temp['a'].str.lower()
    temp['c'] = temp['a'].str.upper()
    return temp

pool = Pool(4)
start = time.time()
out = pool.map(new_df, [9999,10000,10001,10002])
print(f"{time.time() - now} sec")
```

**Issues - VisualStudioCode**

```
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Comment: "The below code seems to have some issues" do you plan on describing those issues to us?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Apologies, thought everyone will experience the issue.

Comment: The error shown is self-explanatory and has nothing to do with Visual Studio Code

Comment: Did you try using the approach that the error message suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code reconstructed  to utilise the main module idiom:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def new_df(rows=10000):
    temp = pd.DataFrame({'a': [''.join(chr(random.randint(65,122)) for _ in range(200))
                               for _ in range(rows)]})
    temp['b'] = temp['a'].str.lower()
    temp['c'] = temp['a'].str.upper()
    return temp

def main():
    start = time.perf_counter()
    with Pool(4) as pool:
        pool.map(new_df, [9999, 10000, 10001, 10002])
    print(f"{time.perf_counter() - start:.2f}s")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
1.24s
```